# cmd throwing error when executing batch file

Tags: batch-file, oracle11g, sqlplus

I'm trying to connect to sqlplus using batch file. I have the following code. when i run the batch file the command prompt is throwing error "The filename, directory name, or volumen label syntax is incorrect.
but it is working fine in another machine. i can't understand the problem. the same is connecting when i type the commands in cmd directly without running batch file.

```
setlocal
set raaga=raaga1

set ORACLE_HOME=C:\Oracle\product\11.2.3\dbhome_1
set ORACLE_SID=%raaga%
set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

(
Echo connect sys/manager22@%raaga% as SYSDBA;
) | Sqlplus /nolog
```

Do i need to install anything? any help is appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: why is this complicated way to pass arguments to `sqlplus` ? can't you just use `sqlplus /nolog connect "sys/manager22@%raaga%" as SYSDBA;` ?

Comment: i need to run some more commands in the sql, which are dynamic and are set using cmd. hence i must follow the mentioned procedure.